# Error installing Rmpi on Mac - "Cannot find mpi.h header file"

Tags: r

I have am trying to install Rmpi in my R software. I am using a Mac Studio M1 running Version 13.4.1, and R version 4.3.1. When I try R to install Rmpi, I receive the following error

```
> install.packages("Rmpi", type="source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rmpi_0.7-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106380 bytes (103 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 103 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rmpi’ ...
** package ‘Rmpi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... clang -arch arm64
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang -arch arm64 accepts -g... yes
checking for clang -arch arm64 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pkg-config... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -arch arm64 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking mpi.h usability... no
checking mpi.h presence... no
checking for mpi.h... no
configure: error: "Cannot find mpi.h header file"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpi’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Rmpi’
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have followed the instructions on this page
https://fisher.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/, including using my terminal to make sure homebrew, gcc, and open-mpi are downloaded. Below is also the output from my command line terminal confirming openmpi and gcc.

```
name@MacStudio ~ % brew install gcc
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: gcc 13.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 13.2.0, run:
  brew reinstall gcc
name@MacStudio ~ % brew install open-mpi
Warning: open-mpi 5.0.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 5.0.1, run:
  brew reinstall open-mpi
```

However, I still receive the error above when I try to install Rmpi.

Comment: What do you get for `which mpirun` in a terminal window? If openmpi is brew installed, you should see something like `/opt/homebrew/bin/mpirun`.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Yes, when i put `which mpirun` into terminal, I receive the following `/opt/homebrew/bin/mpirun` back

Comment: I just checked and get the same error with `Rmpi` on an M3 Mac but another OpenMPI-facing package `pbdMPI` installs fine. So I think it is an issue with `Rmpi` install scripts. Can you elaborate why you need `Rmpi`? Perhaps you can use `pbdMPI` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using `Rmpi` as the parallel backend for the `foreach` package.  I am using `%dopar%` from the `foreach` package and saving the outputs from each parallel running loop as a list that are then combined using mapply.  From what I can tell `pbdMPI` does not work with `foreach`

Comment: Did the `Rmpi` install with `configure.args` work for you? If not, there are easy ways to use `pbdMPI` for your needs without `%dopar%` and `foreach` using a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Rmpi` install sript does not know how to find `brew`-installed `OpenMPI`. Consider using the newer package `pbdMPI`, which installs fine on my M1 and M3 macs with brew-installed `OpenMPI` (`Rmpi` fails on both).

If you need `Rmpi` (possibly as a dependency of another package) specifying the location of the brew-installed `OpenMPI` is needed. Check your `OpenMPI` location with

```
ompi_info | grep Prefix
```

in a terminal window. I am using `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.1` below. Substitute your location if different. Then install `Rmpi` in an R session with

```
install.packages("Rmpi", configure.args = "--with-Rmpi-include=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.1/include -with-Rmpi-libpath=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.1/lib --with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI")
```

where you explicitly specify the include and lib locations, and MPI type.